# How to escape the second capture group the first time in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

It would be helpful if someone could help me in suggesting a way to escape the second capture group the first time. The expression is as follows:

```
(\d)(?=(\d{3})(\d{2})+(?!\d))
```

I want the second capture group `(\d{2})` to be skipped the first time and this group to be evaluated `(\d{3})` just once.

The idea is to find position of a number. Right now, 1000000000 is being evaluated as  1,00,00,00000. I want it to be 1,00,00,00,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this should work for you:

```
"1000000000".replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}(?!\d))/g, "$&,")
```

I dropped all the unnecessary capturing groups, and use `$&` to refer to the main match instead of capturing `\d`.